# Do a Click lock and drag using Catalina OS. (Mouse not a trackpad)

Tags: mac, catalina, assistive-technology

How do I do a Click lock and drag using Catalina OS. I am using a Kensington track ball. I have a  disability that makes it very difficult to hold down the button and spin the ball at the same time.